# Maximum call stack size exceeded error when using ajax multiple times

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am writing a piece of code that should catch all ajax responses on a page. I managed to do this by overriding XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange for javascript direct ajax or by using ajaxComplete() for jQuery ajax.

My problem happens when I try to use ajax multiple times without creating a new XMLHttpObject, for example:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", '/echo/json/', true);
xhr.send();
xhr.open("GET", '/echo/json/', true);
xhr.send()
```

This makes my code go haywire and I get the maximum stack error.
Here is my testing code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zxCfW/

```
var s_ajaxListener = {};
s_ajaxListener.tmpSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
s_ajaxListener.callback = function () {
    console.log('additional state change');
};

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
  s_ajaxListener.tmpOnReadyStateChange = this.onreadystatechange;

  this.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (s_ajaxListener.tmpOnReadyStateChange){
          s_ajaxListener.tmpOnReadyStateChange.apply(this, arguments);
      }
      if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          s_ajaxListener.callback();
          this.onreadystatechange = s_ajaxListener.tmpOnReadyStateChange;
      }
    };

  s_ajaxListener.tmpSend.apply(this, arguments);
};
$(document).ajaxComplete(s_ajaxListener.callback);
```

I believe this happens because the ajax calls are asynchronous so the original onreadystatechange doesn't reset to its default value, but I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Check whether you've already reassigned `this.onreadystatechange`, and don't redo it.

Comment: @zzz, Dont mix jQuery ajax with XMLHTTPRequest. Since you want to cache all the ajax response, You can use $.ajaxSetup instead of writing you own. However writing own code is always developers preference, your code should not conflict with other part of code.